# How to understand the RLstep in Keepaway (Compare with Sarsa)

Tags: reinforcement-learning, sarsa

In "Stone, Peter, Richard S. Sutton, and Gregory Kuhlmann. "Reinforcement learning for robocup soccer keepaway." Adaptive Behavior 13.3 (2005): 165-188.", the RLstep pseudocode seems quite a bit different from Sarsa(λ), which the authors say RLStep implements.

Here is the [RLstep pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpp8P.png) and here is the [Sarsa(lambda) pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cFXy.png).

The areas of confusion are:

- Line 10 in the Sarsa(λ) pseudocode updates the Q value for each
  state-action pair *after* adding 1 to the `e(s,a)`. But in the RLstep
  pseudocode the eligibility trace update (line 19) doesn't happen
  until after the value update (line 17).
- Lines 18 and 19 in RLstep seem quite different from the Sarsa(λ) pseudocode.
- What are lines 20-25 doing with the eligibility trace?